# I want remove repeated records and remove those lines in awk

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, elasticsearch

I want check repeated records in column 2 and remove those lines in awk

```
create a
delete a
create b
create c
delete c
create d
delete f
create f
create g
create h
```

Expected Output

```
create b
create d
create g
create h
```

tried on awk using this command but getting other way, but not exact result

note: AWK is not mandatory

```
awk -F" " '{ if( (++count[$2]==2) ) print  }'
```

Comment: It just an iteration and save the unique records into another file. Is aws mandatory?

Comment: is the delete line always after the create line, when there is a delete?  or could these lines be interleaved?

Comment: Can `create a` appear again later in the file or does each `create` line only appear once per key (2nd field) value? If it can, show in your example how that should be handled.

Comment: create  line only appear once per key @EdMorton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "repeated record", you mean repeated on consecutive lines.  If not, and you want to consider unique records in the whole file, then sort the data on the second field first (`sort -k 2,2 file`).

Using `uniq`:

```bash
$ uniq -f 1 -u file
create b
create d
create g
create h
```

This ignores the first blank-delimited field when doing comparisons (`-f 1`), and then outputs all lines that are *not* duplicated on consecutive lines (`-u`).